# Isomorphic and quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ is a quotient group of $H$ and $H$ is a quotient group of $G$. Can we say that two groups are isomorphic?

Comment: consider two groups are infinite groups.

Comment: The answer is no. It is easy to think of infinitely generated abelian examples as direct products of finite groups. It is considerably more challenging to find finitely generated examples.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095028

Comment: Is it still true for any countable abelian groups?

Comment: No. Use Nex's example but with the restricted direct product (i.e. only finitely many componenets nontrivial).

Comment: Sorry... I am a bit confused. So you mean for countable abelian groups, their quotients are isomorphic,yes???

Answer (score 0):

Let $H =\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times H$. The the product projection $\pi_1: G\to H$ is a quotient. $\phi : H\to G$ defined by $\phi((x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = (x_1,(x_{n+1})_{n\in\mathbb{N}})$ is also a quotient. The two groups are not isomorphic since $G$ has an element $g$ of order two which is not of the form $x+x$ for any $x$ in $G$ while $H$ does not.

Edited to include a countable example:
Let $H =\bigoplus_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}_4$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times H$. The the product projection $\pi_1: G\to H$ is a quotient. $\phi : H\to G$ defined by $\phi((x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = (x_1,(x_{n+1})_{n\in\mathbb{N}})$ is also a quotient. The two groups are not isomorphic since $G$ has an element $g$ of order two which is not of the form $x+x$ for any $x$ in $G$ while $H$ does not.

Comment: Thank you... I want to know about countable abelian groups?!!