# Two non-isomorphic groups which are epimorphic images of each other

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups, I am looking for an example such that $G$ is an epimorphic image of $H$ and $H$ is an epimorphic image of $G$ (i.e. they are both quotients of the other group), but they are not isomorphic. If they are finite, then of course they must be isomorphic, but I am curious if this fails for infinite groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $G=\prod_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \prod_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $G$ is an epimorphic image of $H$ (by projecting the $i$'th coordinate of $H$ to the $(i-1)$'th coordinate of $G$, and $H$ is an epimorphic image of $G$ by sending the first coordinate to its projection in $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and the other coordinates to themselves.  However, $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic, since $G$ does not contain elements of finite order, while $H$ does.

Comment: There are even finitely generated examples. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095028