# $G_1$ a subquotient of $G_2$ and $G_2$ a subquotient of $G_1$, is $G_1 \cong G_2$?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, finitely-generated

Sorry for a presumably noobish group theory question.  I would like an example of the following:

$G_1,G_2$ are finitely presented groups such that there exists finitely presented groups $C_1,C_2$ with the property that $G_1 \twoheadrightarrow C_1 \leftarrowtail G_2$ and $G_2 \twoheadrightarrow C_2 \leftarrowtail G_1$ but $G_1 \ncong G_2$.

Maybe someone who knows a little group theory can put $F_3$ in a 2-generated finitely presented group?  Or maybe that never happens...

I would also like to know of conditions on $G_1, G_2$ that imply that this can not happen.  One condition is if either of the groups is abelian, but I would be interested in hearing other conditions.

Comment: $F_2$ and $F_3$ embed into each other (so are isomorphic to subquotients of each other).

Comment: Even with f.g. nilpotent groups there are examples (the integral Heisenberg group contains a copy of itself as subgroup of finite index, but in between there is another subgroup that is not isomorphic).

Comment: @Ycor Thanks, sorry I'm a bit slow with this, what groups are playing the roles of $G_i, C_i$ in the Heisenberg example?

Comment: Write $u(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}1&x&z\\0&1&y\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$, $G_1=C_1=u(\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z})\simeq u(2\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z},2\mathbf{Z})$ and  $G_2=C_2=u(2\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z},\mathbf{Z})$. The abelianization of $G_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}^2\times\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: @YCor - Thanks!  I think I will close this but I appreciate the examples.

Comment: There are even two nonisomorphic group which appear as finite index subgroups of each other. They are of the form $\mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes \mathbb{Z}$, where the automorphism is given by multiplication with some unit in $\mathbb{Z}/n$. Any maybe even weirder; crossing both of them with $\mathbb{Z}$ gives isomorphic groups.

Comment: And there are non-isomorphic  finitely presented groups that are quotients of each other.

Comment: @HenrikRüping my Heisenberg example already had this finite-index feature (but I like your example, which is independently interesting — I knew it for the other property you mention, namely direct product with $\mathbf{Z}$, and for the related fact they have isomorphic profinite completion).

Comment: Interesting non-answered harder question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282667/are-there-two-non-isomorphic-finitely-presented-groups-which-are-retracts-of-eac

Comment: Examples of non-isomorphic finitely presented groups that are isomorphic to quotients of each other: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1095228/35400